# Heartbeat on Centos linux error message

Tags: linux, centos, heartbeat

this is the error message I get:

```
heartbeat[22269]: 2012/03/21_07:36:55 ERROR: Illegal directive [unicast] in /etc/ha.d/ha.cf
heartbeat[22269]: 2012/03/21_07:36:55 ERROR: Heartbeat not started: configuration error.
heartbeat[22269]: 2012/03/21_07:36:55 ERROR: Configuration error, heartbeat not started.
```

this is my ha.cf file:

```
logfile /var/log/ha-log
###logfacility local0
keepalive 1
deadtime 10
initdead 90
udpport 694
unicast eth0 "node02_IP_Address
auto_failback on
node node01 
node node02
###respawn hacluster /usr/lib/heartbeat/ipfail
```

any idea
thanks,
E.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The directive for Unicast is 'ucast' not 'unicast:

```
logfile /var/log/ha-log
###logfacility local0
keepalive 1
deadtime 10
initdead 90
udpport 694
ucast eth0 node02_IP_Address
auto_failback on
node node01
node node02
###respawn hacluster /usr/lib/heartbeat/ipfail
```

Answer (score 2):

As the error message you get states, `unicast` is not a valid configuration option. You should use `ucast` instead, if my memory serves me right.